# Proposal: Creation of Actuarial Science SE

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, best-practices, area51

I have noticed that there are quite a few (un-answered) questions with the actuarial science tag in the Mathematics SE and also on Cross Validated.

To increase the response rate of these types of questions, and to restrict the Mathematics SE solely to math questions, is there a voting process by which an Actuarial Science SE can be created, if enough people vote for it?

Comment: Aside from [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @pjs36 I understand that Area 51 is the formal process to get site management to create it. By posting the question here in the Mathematics Meta, I was hoping to gain the opinions of the Mathematics SE members, to see if they're annoyed at seeing actuarial questions, and would find it easier if there was a separate forum to deal with actuarial questions.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question then. Right now your question reads "is there a voting process by which an Actuarial Science SE can be created, if enough people vote for it?" and the answer is "Area 51". I see that you've created [a proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94022/actuarial-science) already, you may want to link to it too.

Comment: It seems that there [was a proposal like this before](https://www.google.com/search?q=actuarial+science+site:area51.stackexchange.com). However, it was [deleted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60004/actuarial-science).

Comment: Since you wrote that you were "hoping to gain the opinions of the Mathematics SE members, to see if they're annoyed at seeing actuarial questions", I will add a link to this older discussion on meta: [Why are actuarial science questions considered off topic?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/why-are-actuarial-science-questions-considered-off-topic)